# Convert PyQGIS processing script to plugin and get same user interface

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I have written a PyQGIS processing script that can be used from Toolbox. I would like to convert this to plugin and publish. The script is taking input and output from the user through processing algorithm built-in parameter Ccasses.

[image]

If I convert this to plugin using the Plugin Builder 3 plugin. Will it generate the same user interface? If not what is the right way of converting a toolbox script to plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a skeleton for processing plugin from the "QGIS plugin builder".

You should more or less use the instructions from this tutorial https://www.qgistutorials.com/sl/docs/3/processing_python_plugin.html
You will need to adapt them due to your own plugin particularities.

By default, the generated plugin does not contain the help part (right content) but by adding in your own plugin the method `shortHelpString`, it works fine (see [the ScriptTemplate.py file](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptTemplate.py#L88) from the QGIS repo for an ilustration). See below screen capture as a proof :)

[image: capture plugin with processing algorithm]

Comment: Thank you. It looks like this is pretty much all that I need. Do you know if we can tweak the interface as well if we use this approach? For example, I would like to group all my output parameters under the heading of Output Parameters and put them at the bottom?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no GUI reference in the plugin itself (so I don't see how you could tweak). GUI generated by the config from the provider and internal to QGIS (if not, I'm not aware)

Comment: Do you know If I have some layer styles files and a table file referenced in my script, how can I publish along that embedded with the plugin so that plugin can work at any machine? Currently, the files are at my C drive and are referenced by the script.

Comment: Search string `self.plugin_dir` and `locale_path =` in your generated plugin files for an example (relative path already used for locale e.g translation)